# How can I create a template .csv file that users can fill in before running my script?

Tags: python, validation, csv, input

I am trying to make a script that requires a user to input at least 12 different values in order to function. I thought this was somewhat impractical, so I decided to make a function that would generate dict from a .csv file that was designed with two columns– variables and their respective values. The user could use a provided .csv file as a template and then fill it in with all their necessary values, save it as their own .csv file, and then run it with the script.

Although this sounds simple in theory, I have found that is not working quite so well in practice. Because some of the inputs values will be text with a lot of periods in them ("..."), they are sometimes converted into the unicode representing horizontal ellipses (xe2\x80\xa6). Also, a UTF-8 mark will occur at the beginning of the first column and row (which can be designated by the code `codecs.BOM_UTF8`), and must be removed. In other cases, the delimiter of the .csv file was changed so that tabs were recognized as separating cells, or the contents of each row were converted from two to one cell.

I have no experience with the different forms of encoding or what any of them entail, but from what I have tested, it seems that opening the .csv template file in Excel or using different settings when opening your .csv file causes such problems. It's also possible that copying and pasting the values from other places brings hidden characters with them. I have been trying to fix the problems but then new problems keep springing up, and I feel like it's possible that my current approach is just wrong.

Can anybody recommend me a different, more efficient approach for allowing a user to enter in multiple inputs in one go? Or should I stick to my original approach and figure out how to keep the .csv formatting as rigorous as possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use the csv module to abstract away most of the CSV oddities (although you will have to enforce the basic format):

```
import csv
import sys

def main(argv):
    if len(argv) < 2:
        print("Please provide path to your CSV template as the first argument.")
        return 1
    with open(argv[1], "r") as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        your_vars = next(reader)
    print(your_vars)  # prints a dictionary of all CSV vars
    return 0

if __name__ == "main":
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

**NOTE**: This requires the first *row* to hold the variables, while the second holds their values.

So all users have to do is call the script with: `python your_script.py their_file.csv` and in most cases it will print out a dict with the values... However, Excel is notoriously bad in handling unicode CSVs and if your users use it as their primary spreadsheet app they're likely to encounter issues. Some of that can be rectified by installing the [unicodecsv](https://github.com/jdunck/python-unicodecsv) module and using it as a drop-in replacement (`import unicodecsv as csv`) but if your users start going wild with the format eventually it will break.

If you're looking for suggestions on formats, one of the most user-friendly formats you can use is YAML and there are several parsers available for Python - they largely work the same for the simple stuff like this but I'd recommend using the [ruamel.yaml](https://bitbucket.org/ruamel/yaml) module as it's actively maintained.

Then you can create a YAML template like:

```
----
var1: value1
var2: value2
var3: value3
etc: add as many as you want
```

And your users can fill in the values in a simple text editor, then to replicate the above CSV behavior all you need is:

```
import yaml
import sys

def main(argv):
    if len(argv) < 2:
        print("Please provide path to your YAML template as the first argument.")
        return 1
    with open(argv[1], "r") as f:
        your_vars = yaml.load(f)
    print(your_vars)  # prints a dictionary of all YAML vars
    return 0

if __name__ == "main":
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

Bonus is that YAML is plain-text format so your users don't need fancy editors and therefore they have a lesser chance to screw up. Of course, while YAML is permissive it still requires modicum of well-formedness so be sure to include the usual checks (if the file exists, can it be open, can it be parsed etc.)

Comment: Thanks so much for such a comprehensive response! But I should have mentioned, when I call this script, the user will actually need to enter two separate .csv files, the other of which is already predefined (and thus is not subject to same formatting errors as my previously described .csv file). So can I add in an additional file to be opened in the main(argv) function? Furthermore, I do have plans in the future to implement this code in a command line program with argparse module (which I've started learning recently). Can I still use this function with argprase?

Comment: You can use it however you like, those are just example scripts to show you how to load and parse the file to get your external variables. Technically, the main business logic in both cases is between `with open(argv[1], "r") as f:` and `print(your_vars)` lines, everything outside is just a supporting code. You can use pretty much any path coming from anywhere, be it directly from `argv` list or through `argparse`, and as long as the file exists and is valid you'll get your vars.